# Best way to allow user to upload larger video files?

Tags: file-upload, upload

I want users to upload video files which can be larger in size. I have created simple upload script and can allow larger files by doing some changes in php.ini but Is there any better way that I can learn and create ? Please help me with what I can learn for this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to use any upload library which will handle all you upload requirement. If you will write your own, you might miss lot of use cases which is already developed already.

You can customize it as per your requirement and add what ever required in top of that.

You need to think something which have resume, pause, etc facility as network or other problem may happen. you can try this http://resumablejs.com/

If you want to convert, compress you can use FFmpeg (https://ffmpeg.org)

Comment: Thanks @Aniruddha. Will check :)

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps look into chunking - basically, slicing up a large file into smaller files. This could allow your uploads to be more resilient to any failures and you could even allow for pausing/resuming uploads. Also, since the file is going to be sent in smaller chunks, you won't need to configure your php.ini to allow for ridiculously large uploads.

Check out [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/docs/Chunking). They have a good page on chunking and provide code samples for you to get started.

Comment: Thanks!! Will check it out.

Comment: I think he is changing php.ini to increase file upload size, and max post upload size which is required to receive large file. first we need to allow server to receive large file then the upload strategy by chunking, pause capability, etc.